# Howler.js not loading sounds with Parcel bundler

Tags: javascript, parceljs, howler.js

There's a problem here with Howler and Parcel interacting together. "it has been loaded" never logs. The log of test works and logs the proper howler audio object, however the loading state is "loading" and it never loads.

It's been confirmed that the problem is with the interaction with Parcel, because loading this file with the Live Server VS Code plugin plays the sound correctly.

I have been really impressed with Parcel and this is the first problem I've encountered with it, however I've not learned how to debug it when it doesn't work. Any idea on what's going wrong here and how to start debugging Parcel?

```
import { Howl, Howler } from 'howler';

const test = new Howl({
  src: "laser1.mp3",
  onload() {
    console.log("it has been loaded!")
  }
})
console.log(test);

test.play();
```